# Gremlin Query to count Edges - MemoryLimitExceededException AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

Gremlin Query on Neptune to count no of edges for vertexes with certain label results in `MemoryLimitExceededException`. Error only occurs a few times i.e. if i run query 10 times, succeeds twice.

Neptune is using `db.r5.xlarge`.

Query

```
g.V().hasLabel('MyVertex').has('myLabel',1234).outE().hasLabel('MY_EDGE_LABEL').count().next()
```

There are over 3 million vertices with label `MyVertex` and 1 million edges matching `MY_EDGE_LABEL` edge label.

Error:

```
{
    "code": "MemoryLimitExceededException",
    "requestId": "123456-abcd-1234-1234-11aa221122ab",
    "detailedMessage": "Query cannot be completed due to memory limitations."
}
```

My Questions:

- Is there any setting like memory limit for a query on Neptune that can be increased?
- Is there anything in the query that can be adjusted to get same result but consumes less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a limit(1) to limit the size of the result has fixed the problem.

> g.V().hasLabel('MyVertex').has('myLabel',1234).outE().hasLabel('MY_EDGE_LABEL').count().limit(1).next()